# How do i make this layout in css, divs are collapsing

Tags: html, css

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/csfvb91u/

(just realized normal div is collapsing ALSO to size of content, is min height completely useless?)

I need two divs, one **left**, and on **right**. Left one is 100px wide and stays that way. While, **right** div **expands infinitely** and doesn't shrink beyond 400px. Both Divs should be the height of parent. And **parent** has no exact height but **minimum height of 800**. So if content of one of these 2 divs were to push the height of div and extend it. Then The height of parent should increase and thus also the height of other div.

I tried using floats. I managed to some extent. However left side which was on float left, its height kept collapsing and didn't follow height:100% rule. It only worked if parent had definite width.

I tried using inline block but then right div won't expand to fillin the available space..

[image]

*Why in the world css doesn't have fit-content, fill-available, choose what % refers to, choose what to position against, use vector or use pngs to shape div, inset textshadow, etc.*

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try table layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for child you will need to give fixed with for the left div

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/z90fma6e/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.left,
.right {
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
.right {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="left">fixed
    <br/>height adjusts</div>
  <div class="right">expands
    <br/>height adjusts</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok this works, but can you explain why empty normal div is collapsing in my fiddle, ive set height to be 100% and parent does have minimum height which is being applied.

Comment: because i have set parent height to `100%`

Comment: i am talking about my fiddle

Comment: you have not used table layout here is your updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/csfvb91u/2/)

Comment: float, absolute, and all don't work for this type of layout Only this provides everything.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your divs are collapsing. Your going to need a clearfix you can add to divs. There are a few ways to do this; however, this option is best.

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

Add this clearfix class and css to your divs so they wont collapse.

You can read more about them at [cssTricks](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

perfect use case for CSS flex layout:

```
<style>
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  div:first-child {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
  }
  div:last-child {
    flex: 1;
    background: blue;
  }
</style>

<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: i wish i could use flex.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer why? what browsers you are going to support?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Well that's sad, then you may adopt the answer from Vitorino Fernandes. But don't forget to vote me up once you are free to use flex :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to support IE8 or earlier I would suggest you to use positioning:

Here's what I came up with

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/csfvb91u/4/

If the content on the right is going out of the container, you can always use margin-right:200px as the right side container is shifted 200px using left:200px. Hope you get what I'm saying... :)

HTML:

```
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .a {
        position:absolute;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: green;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .b {
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        left:200px;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .cont {
        position:relative;    
        border:1px solid #333;
        min-height:300px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: the problem with this then becomes that content of .b won't expand the height of .cont. As .b when positioned absolute is out of flow and thus .cont doesn't care how big it's.
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/csfvb91u/11/

Comment: i found someway to do it, If you make right div to be normal div but give 200px left margin then it works as long as content of left div doesn't exceed it in height.

Comment: that's the exact thing I said, left margin, if you would really like to see a live example of this kind of layout, check my site http://www.redpeppermedia.in/